# String de una Thread a un Label

Tags: c#, hilos

Tengo `Thread`, que me genera una "consulta" (este trabaja en un `form` distinto al principal) y me gustaría enviar una variable de tipo `string` (que es generada por la consulta) para que se muestre en un `Label` que esta en el primer From (principal) automáticamente cuando termine de realizar la "consulta" el thread.

He encintado como pasar datos de un `form` a otro pero en los ejemplos siempre hay que presionar un botón, o el `label` o `textbox` cambia sólo cuando se abre (`show`).

No sé si me explico, quiero algo que sea más dinámico que al momento de tener respuesta pueda mostrarla en seguida en el `label` del `form` principal... Me imagino como activar el evento `textchange` o algo así.

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos tu código? Que has intentado y como lo has hecho.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo no usar `Thread`.Es una clase compleja de utilizar y es muy facil tener problemas. C# cuenta con herramientas mejores, como [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) y `Task`. Backgroundworker tiene los métodos `ProgressChanged` y `RunWorkerCompleted`que te sirven perfectamente para lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con eventos:

```
public class MiFormConThread
{
    public event EventHandler CuandoTerminaMiThread;

    void MiThread()
    {
        (new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                MiConsulta();               

                //#Opción 1
                if (CuandoTerminaMiThread != null)
                    CuandoTerminaMiThread("Mi String", EventArgs.Empty);

                //#Opcion 2 (en C# 6)
                //CuandoTerminaMiThread?.Invoke("Mi String", EventArgs.Empty);

            })).Start();
    }
}

public class MiFormPrincipal
{
    public MiFormPrincipal()
    {
        MiFormConThread form2 = new MiFormConThread();
        form2.CuandoTerminaMiThread += form2_CuandoTerminaMiThread;
    }

    void form2_CuandoTerminaMiThread(object sender, EventArgs e)//sender es el string que pasamos en MiFormConThread
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            label1.Text = sender.ToString();

            //C# 6
            //label1.Text = $"{sender}";
        });
    }
}
```